# How to create a Sonar rule to parse a custom XML file in Java?

Tags: java, xml, sonarqube

We have custom XML files generated from a tool, however, we need to create some rules such as whether an XML element is referenced in other XML files etc. We couldn't find any information on the SonarQube or anywhere else. Anyone has any idea on how to write a Java class to execute a Sonar rule on an XML file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write your own plugin based on the SonarQube official XML Plugin http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/XML+Plugin.

Comment: Hi Leo, your question was asked long ago but I face the same task now and I would be keen to know your experiences. Do you have any particular advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the coding rules. You must follow the insturctions of SonarQube online documentations. See: [Extending Coding Rules](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Extension+Guide).
For examples you should checkout the repository of [SonarQube examples](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Getting+Started).